# Mapping fields inside other fields

Tags: python, node.js, database, mapping, etl

Hello I would like to make an app that allows the user to import data from a source of his choice (Airtable, xls, csv, JSON) and export to a JSON which will be pushed to an Sqlite database using an API.

The "core" of the functionality of the app is that it allows the user to create a "template" and "map" of the source columns inside the destination columns. Which source column(s) go to which destination column is up to the user. I am attaching two photos here (used in airtable/zapier), so you can get a better idea of the end result:
[adding fields inside fields - airtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vQ7V.gif)[adding fields inside fields - zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAKAR.gif)

I would like to know if you can recommend a library or a way to come about this problem? I have tried to look for some python or nodejs libraries, I am lost between using ETL libraries, some recommended using mapping/zipping features, others recommend coding my own classes. Do you know any libraries that allow to do the same thing as airtable/zapier ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Save file on databases is really a bad practice since it takes up a lot of database storage space and would add latency in the communication.

I hardly recommend saving it on disk and store the path on database.

Comment: The file will not be saved inside the database. The data will be converted from Json and stored inside the Sqlite through an API. But my question is about the mapping, not the actual storage after the mapping.